# merging in pandas vs merging in R

Tags: python, r, join, merge, pandas

I'm afraid I do not quite understand the merging capabilities of pandas, although I much prefer python over R for now.

In R, I have always been able to merge dataframes very easily as follows:

```
> merge(test,e2s, all.x=T)
      Gene                 Mutation Chromosome Entrez
1     AGRN                  p.R451H       chr1 375790
2 C1orf170            p.V663A/V683A       chr1  84808
3     HES4                   p.R44S       chr1  57801
4    ISG15                   p.S83N       chr1   9636
5  PLEKHN1 p.S476P/S511P/S563P/S76P       chr1  84069
```

However, I have been unable to reconstruct this in pandas with merge(how="left,right,inner,outer").. For example:

```
Outer yields a union, which makes sense:
x = test.merge(e2s, how="outer")
In [133]: x.shape
Out[133]: (46271, 4)
```

But inner yields an empty dataframe, even though `Entrez_Gene_Id` has been merged successfully:

```
In [143]: x = test.merge(e2s, how="inner")

In [144]: x
Out[144]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene, Mutation, Chromosome, Entrez_Gene_Id]
Index: []

[0 rows x 4 columns]
```

The intersection should contain one row with the `gene : HES4`. Is there some sort of string matching I need to turn on for this?:

e2s:

```
57794   SUGP1
57795   BRINP2
57796   DKFZP761C1711
57798   GATAD1
57799   RAB40C
57801   HES4
57804   POLD4
57805   CCAR2
57817   HAMP
```

test:

```
       Gene                  Mutation Chromosome
0   PLEKHN1  p.S476P/S511P/S563P/S76P       chr1
1  C1orf170             p.V663A/V683A       chr1
2      HES4                    p.R44S       chr1
3     ISG15                    p.S83N       chr1
4      AGRN                   p.R451H       chr1
5    RNF223                   p.P242H       chr1
```

**Update:**

As far as I know the columns are labelled so that they should merge fine, I only want to merge by the `Gene` column and keep all test rows:

```
In [148]: e2s.columns
Out[148]: Index([u'Gene', u'Entrez_Gene_Id'], dtype='object')

In [149]: test.columns
Out[149]: Index([u'Gene', u'Mutation', u'Chromosome'], dtype='object')
```

This was done by explicitly renaming the dataframes:

```
e2s.rename(columns={"Gene":u'Gene',"Entrez_Gene_Id":u'Entrez_Gene_Id'}, inplace=True)
```

to dict:

```
{u'Chromosome': {0: u'chr1',
  1: u'chr1',
  2: u'chr1',
  3: u'chr1',
  4: u'chr1',
  5: u'chr1'},
 u'Gene': {0: u'PLEKHN1',
  1: u'C1orf170',
  2: u'HES4',
  3: u'ISG15',
  4: u'AGRN',
  5: u'RNF223'},
 u'Mutation': {0: u'p.S476P/S511P/S563P/S76P',
  1: u'p.V663A/V683A',
  2: u'p.R44S',
  3: u'p.S83N',
  4: u'p.R451H',
  5: u'p.P242H'}}

{u'Entrez_Gene_Id': {14118: u'SUGP1',
  14119: u'BRINP2',
  14120: u'DKFZP761C1711',
  14121: u'GATAD1',
  14122: u'RAB40C',
  14123: u'HES4',
  14124: u'POLD4',
  14125: u'CCAR2',
  14126: u'HAMP'},
 u'Gene': {14118: 57794,
  14119: 57795,
  14120: 57796,
  14121: 57798,
  14122: 57799,
  14123: 57801,
  14124: 57804,
  14125: 57805,
  14126: 57817}}
```

Comment: Here are some comparions: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=395

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment: it's not an encoding problem, the issue is that the column names are incorrect/switched in e2s, hence there are no matches. Solved by switching back `e2s.columns = e2s.columns[::-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you haven't labelled the columns (this is needed otherwise how can you know which columns to use to match against!)

It works fine if they are both are frames with labelled columns:

```
In [11]: e2s
Out[11]: 
   number           Gene
0   57794          SUGP1
1   57795         BRINP2
2   57796  DKFZP761C1711
3   57798         GATAD1
4   57799         RAB40C
5   57801           HES4
6   57804          POLD4
7   57805          CCAR2
8   57817           HAMP

In [12]: test
Out[12]: 
       Gene                  Mutation Chromosome
0   PLEKHN1  p.S476P/S511P/S563P/S76P       chr1
1  C1orf170             p.V663A/V683A       chr1
2      HES4                    p.R44S       chr1
3     ISG15                    p.S83N       chr1
4      AGRN                   p.R451H       chr1
5    RNF223                   p.P242H       chr1

In [13]: e2s.merge(test)
Out[13]: 
   number  Gene Mutation Chromosome
0   57801  HES4   p.R44S       chr1

In [14]: test.merge(e2s)
Out[14]: 
   Gene Mutation Chromosome  number
0  HES4   p.R44S       chr1   57801
```

Comment: I believe I had named the columns correctly. Attempted to rename them but am not successfully merging. Thanks for your response, although this is bewildering :)

Comment: @lennart can you include the output of .to_dict() for both these objects, that way we can replicate!

Comment: Hey Andy, would `join` be more appropriate in this instance?

Comment: @PaulH It's a good question, I think it's much of a much-ness really (bost are *fast*) and depends if later it'll help to use Gene as an Index :s

Comment: @AndyHayden thanks a bunch guys, it is probably something silly. Much appreciated.

Comment: @lennart yup, it's something silly! (The columns are labelled differently: Gene is the number and Entrez_Gene_Id is the name! Hence no matches) Maybe switch them with `e2s.columns = e2s.columns[::-1]`.

Comment: great, that fixed it. wasn't a unicode problem after all, I thought I had changed the columns. Thanks @AndyHayden

Comment: @lennart that was my first thought! (I thought maybe it was a python 3 thing, but I thought *surely* someone would have mentioned it before!) Glad you fixed it :)